# Running a recurring task on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

I have a SQL Azure database and I want to run a couple of overnight tasks, every night.

The First task will be a data update, running in a Stored procedure.

The Second task will need to run C# code that will do a number of tasks, including making calls to the database, processing data and sending emails.

I'm leaning towards using Azure WebJobs for each of these tasks, but I though there might be a better way that I have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Azure WebJob would likely be a good choice for this. In term of scheduling the WebJob, the preferred way is to use the CRON approach described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON).

Comment: It seems like the answer is down to your coding preference. I am accepting this answer, as it seems the most flexible to me.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Automation is another options that many folks have used: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/

Although the service is based on PowerShell, one can upload and reference C# dlls.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't Scheduler supposed to do this on Azure? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/

Comment: Stored procedures:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ms-tech_learning_with_prasant/archive/2014/07/09/scheduling-job-on-sql-azure.aspx

Comment: This shows how to add a script in C#, but I will need to include libraries too.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was asked in 2015 much has changed.

If you were looking at this today then [Azure Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) would be the likely answer.  Logic Apps are [replaced deprecated Azure Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/migrate-from-scheduler-to-logic-apps)

Depending on exactly what your tasks entail you could adapt it to run [natively within](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/built-in#manage-or-manipulate-data) the Logic App, port it to one or more of the connectors or indeed [connect back to on-premise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/managed#on-premises-connectors) if that is required.